# Comparing that two text files are identical C#

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm trying to compare two text files and check if they are identical otherwise I'll be returning `false`.

The two text files I'm comparing are identical but the result bool is `false`.

```
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(@"..\..\..\Test\expected_result_1.txt");                        
StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(@"\temp_dir\result01.txt");
result = compareFiles(ref sr1,ref sr2);
```

And here I have the function:

```
public bool compareFiles(ref StreamReader file1, ref StreamReader file2)
{
    bool result = true;
    while (!file1.EndOfStream)
    {
        if (file1.Read() != file2.Read())
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result)
    {
        if (!file2.EndOfStream)
        {
            result = false;
        }  
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Update:** The two text files are identical so I compared them in a hex editor and the hex dump was slightly different. What should be done when encountering this issue?

Comment: how big are the files?

Comment: you could use `MD5` for comparison if I understand your scenario correctly, Precompute the hash for the test and just generate a hash for the file that's to be tested.

Comment: @Vulpex: Not good advice. 1) it's overkill for what the OP has in mind. 2) a hash comparison only tells you that two files are different if the hashes don't match. Hashes can be the same for two non-identical files.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the quesiton was to check if two files are identical, sure `MD5` can be the same however it's not very likely, alternatively use a different hash and depending on the files it could be quite efficient. So I don't really think your reason holds true.

Comment: @Mass provide a sample of both your text files that result in `false` comparison.

Comment: It's a good idea to compare hashes before comparing the files, especially if the files are expected to be different more often than not -- however it doesn't substitute to a proper comparison should the hashes match. In any case, OP needs an answer as to why this seemingly valid code doesn't work for them.

Comment: @Vulpex A hash cannot determine whether two files are identical, just if they are different (however unlikely it may be, that two different files have the same hash). So if you get the same hash, you will have to check the files nonetheless (to be 100% sure). Furthermore, how would hashing two files be more efficient, than just comparing them byte by byte?

Comment: @derpirscher by using a precomputed hash for the test case he has, as stated if I understand his scenario correctly. But I grant you I've probably miscommunicated my intend and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: The files are 1kb so they are not big

Comment: @500-InternalServerError since md5 is 128 bit, wouldn't the risk of accidental collision be 1 in 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456? which is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @Magnus Depending on the scenario The chance is much higher and it's quite easy to construct MD5 collisions. I don't say OP's problem is prone to such attacks, but nonetheless there are reasons why the use of MD5 is discouraged https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value

Comment: @Mass Your code should work. Chances are high, your files are not really identical (linebreaks, trailing whitespaces, there are even "hidden characters" (ie bytes that are not visible in a texteditor) or characters which look like each other, but have different byte values. Set a breakpoint at `result = false` and check the position in the stream where it gets hit. Then check the files with a hex editor at that position ...

Comment: That is why I said "accidental collision". If the file is designed to generated collisions then that is something else. But would you say two identical SHA1 (for example) hashes would not be safe to use for identifying two identical files?

Comment: @derpirscher you are tottaly correct. There are carriage returns in the other file!

Comment: @Magnus Depends on the scenario. For OP's current use, it might be sufficient (even with MD5) If my life depended on it, no I would not trust, especially not MD5 ...

Comment: @Mass The safest way to deal with such issues (different linebreaks, etc) is to make sure the files are generated correctly and in a consistent way. Either adapt the way you create the testresults or the expected results ...

Comment: @ derpirscher yeah I adapted the way the testresults are created and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code.

```
public bool compareFiles(ref StreamReader file1, ref StreamReader file2)
{
  try 
  {
    //Must put that check in a try/catch block, because not every stream
    //supports checking the length.
    if (file1.BaseStream.Length != file2.BaseStream.Length)
      return false;
  } catch {}  //but can safely ignore the exception 

  while (!file1.EndOfStream)
  {
    //once you read different chars from stream, you can return
    if (file1.Read() != file2.Read())
      return false;
  }
  //if you read file1 to the end, file2 must also be at the end 
  return file2.EndOfStream;
}
```

But in prinicple your code should work too. Maybe you have a linebreak in the end of one file, or some trailing whitespaces, ... Have you tried passing the same file in for both parameters? It should return true.

Comment: The 'ref' qualifiers seems unnecessary btw

Comment: If the streams support seeking/length, it might be useful to start by checking that the lengths are the same.

Comment: In the while loop, you can also check `!file2.EndOfStream`.

Comment: @derpirscher I checked and ther is no linebeak at the end of the file. I tried passing the same file in for both parameters and it returned true. Tried to compare the two identical files again and got false as a return value

Comment: I would not pass the streamreaders to the method but just the paths. The method should decide what way to use to check if they are equal. It should first check if the paths are valid and then compare the file-length. Then according to the length of the file it can decide if a simple `File.ReadAllBytes(pathFile1).SequenceEqual(File.ReadAllBytes(pathFile2))` is enough.

Comment: @MeirKlemfner Yes, I can check `!file2.EndOfStream` but it's not necessary to do so, because `file2.Read()` will return `-1` if there is no data left in the stream. And then `file1.Read() != file2.Read()` will evaluate to `true` and the loop will break (and the method will `return false`)

Comment: @TimSchmeler Yes, that would be a possibility, but I decided to keep OP's method signature ...

Comment: @JonasH Yes you are right. Length checking may speed up things (if available)

Answer (score 2):

If the files are small, and if they are text files, which you say they are, then instead of streaming there are higher level methods for file handling. For example:

```
File.ReadAllText(f1) == File.ReadAllText(f2)
```

That will compare the contents of 2 files in 1 line without worrying about is 1 stream longer than the other etc.

Of course it is slower this way, but for 1kb you won't notice.

Another pointer, check if you really need to pass variables to a method using 'ref'. That is not required in the code above. Maybe read up on that.